# Swift enum that has associated values, got "missing argument label 'array' in call"

Tags: swift, enums

I'm learning Swift. Below is my code:

```
enum MyTest
{
    case Point(Int, Int)
    case What(String)
    case GiveMeFunc((array: Int...) -> Int)
}

var p1 = MyTest.Point(2, 2)
var p2 = MyTest.Point(3, 3)

var s1 = MyTest.What("Haha...")
var s2 = MyTest.What("Heihei...")

var f1 = MyTest.GiveMeFunc({(array: Int...) -> Int in return 8})
var f2 = MyTest.GiveMeFunc({(array: Int...) -> Int in return 9})

switch p1 {
    case .What(let string):
        println(string)
    case .GiveMeFunc(let f):
        println(f(1, 2, 4, 3))
    case .Point(let a, let b):
        println("a: \(a)  b: \(b)")
}
```

When I run it I got

```
missing argument label 'array' in call.
```

The error comes from :

```
println(f(1, 2, 4, 3))`
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: @MaximShoustin look in the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inserting the `array:` label:

```
case .GiveMeFunc(let f):
    println(f(array: 1, 2, 4, 3))
```

since the definition of the function requires it:

```
case GiveMeFunc((array: Int...) -> Int)
```

Alternatively if you redefined `GiveMeFunc` to not have a named argument, you wouldn't have to supply it:

```
case GiveMeFunc((Int...) -> Int)
```

Comment: Oh I don't know in `f(array: 1, 2, 4, 3)` `1, 2, 4, 3` are considered as an array. I've tried f(array: [1, 2, 4, 3]) but it does not work. Interesting. Thank you!

Comment: `Int...` is what's called a variadic parameter.  To the caller, it looks like supplying multiple separate arguments, but inside the function itself those are all presented as an array.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the error message: `missing argument label 'array' in call`

If you look at your closure `GiveMeFunc((array: Int...) -> Int)` it takes a parameter called `array`

So the error message is saying that you're missing that parametername

So by doing: `println(f(array: 1, 2, 4, 3))` it works

Or changing the closure to `GiveMeFunc((Int...) -> Int)`